# Update a query using executeUpdate - Error says String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to update the Result table. The code i used to update is given below :

The Domain class Result has the following attribute

```
int rate
```

The code from the controller:

```
Result.executeUpdate("update Result b set b.rate=:rate " +
            "where b.id=:id",
            [rate: params.rate, id: (Long) ((params.id).toInteger())])
```

I end up getting the following error :

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Note: `params.rate` is a `integer`, so how can `update` the query.

Comment: do i miss something very complicated or couldn't you just call `params.rate.toInteger()` like you do already with the id?  also there is `toLong()` if you rather have not a problem in the future with the id beeing clipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: params.rate is a integer, so how can update the query.

Parameter values are always strings (or a list/array of strings) unless you explicitly convert them. Try this instead

```
Result.executeUpdate("update Result b set b.rate=:rate where b.id=:id",
    [rate: params.int('rate'), id: params.long('id')]
)
```